# Rails Integration Test Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial, the author implements integration tests to test layout links.  He uses the syntax:

```
test "layout links" do
```

Is the role of "layout links" to inform the reader what the test is doing, or is it part of the code?

Further down, he runs an `assert_select` to test if the href links are working:

```
assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
```

Why is `[href=?]` in brackets and what role does the question mark play?

Full code for `test/integration/site_layout_test.rb` below:

```
require 'test_helper'
class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "layout links" do
    get root_path
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count: 2
    assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"layout links" is just used to name the test

assert_select is documented [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/SelectorAssertions/assert_select) and can take a CSS selector expression with substitution values ( the ? is where the substitution takes place ) so

assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path

is basically the same as

assert_select "a[href=#{help_path}]"

Comment: Thanks, this helped!